# How to open Chrome Extension on new window instead of the default popup?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, runtime

I'm building a Chrome Extension and I need users to be able to "detach" the extension from the default top-right location of the popup when they so desire. Note that I still want the extension to open normally when the icon is clicked. But I need that when a specific button is clicked, for the extension to close and immediately open itself in a new window with specified dimensions and no URL address bar as per the below picture:

[image]

I've got this code so far but it is not working. Nothing happens when the button is clicked:

```
function createPanel(tab) {
    if (!tab) return; const contentWindowId = tab.windowId;
    try { const panelWindowInfo = chrome.windows.create({
        url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
        type:"popup",
        height: 500,
        width: 300, });
    } catch (error) { console.log(error); }
}  

document.getElementById("myItemX").addEventListener("click", boxX)
function boxX() {
  chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(createPanel);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: onClicked doesn't work with default_popup. Remove `default_popup` from manifest.json, declare a background script, put the chrome.action.onClicked line (not the box function!) + createPanel there. The rest should be in popup.js.

Comment: Yep that works. Although what need is to open the Extension in this way only when the user wants. The default should still be ```default_popup```. That's why I was trying to use this same code within "popup.js" on button click within ```popup.html```. Is this possible? Maybe the code needs to change somehow.

Comment: Call chrome.action.setPopup({popup:''}) to disable default_popup and enable onClicked. The onClicked should be in the background script.

Comment: So adding ```chrome.action.setPopup({popup:''})``` to "popup.js" makes the ```default_popup``` comeback just not via manifest which is necessary right? So now how do I get the onClick event to "detach" the extension into a new window when the button element in "popup.html" is clicked? I mean how do I get the button id via a background script?

Comment: I tried the function for the button from the question and I get the error ```Uncaught ReferenceError: document is not defined```. This makes sense since the "background.js" is not imported into the "popup.html" index file. So maybe there must be a way to listen to the button click event from "background.js" ?

Comment: No. Both setPopup and onClicked are used in the background script, no document necessary. The setPopup can be used to toggle default_popup if you specify an empty string or the original file name. The onClicked will work only after the empty string is specified. The onClicked will simply open a new window, nothing else.

Comment: Ok I'm starting to understand this. Now how to I make an HTML ```<button>``` on "popup.html" open a new Window through this ```onClicked ``` if it needs to be in "background.js"? That's what I don't understand.

Comment: No, onClicked can be only in background.js. It will work after you call setPopup with an empty string next time the extension icon is clicked. If you want to show a new window from an already visible popup then use chrome.windows.create.

Comment: Ok, perfect that ```chrome.windows.create``` is what I needed. I think I'm going to use the answer below as it is so complete because it memorizes position etc. But this helped me understand how the basic function of opening the extension on a new window works. Thanks once again @wOxxOm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "thinned out" an extension of mine.
It should do what you asked and also remember the last position of the detached window.

```
/*manifest.json - begin*/
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "xxx",
    "version": "0.0.0.1",
    "background": { "service_worker": "sw.js" },
    "action": {
        "default_title": "xxx",
        "default_icon": "icon.png"
    },
    "icons": { "16": "icon.png" },
    "permissions": ["storage", "activeTab"]
}
/*manifest.json - end*/

/*popup.html - begin*/
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>xxx</title>
        <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="margin:1px 2px 1px 2px; background:#5f9ea0; overflow-y:hidden; min-width:371px">
        <div style="margin:0 auto; width:97%; font-size:12px">
            <div style="border:1px solid white; margin:3px; display:block">
                <div style="padding: 2px; margin: 0px; border: 0px solid red; height: 55px;">
                    <div id="achPopup" status="" style="width:43px; height: 43px; line-height:21px;  border:1px solid black; text-align:center;">
                        <a>ach<br>Popup</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
/*popup.html - end*/

/*sw.js - begin*/
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener(async t => {
    await chrome.storage.session.set({'windVal':'popup'});
    await chrome.action.setPopup({popup: '../popup.html'});
    await chrome.action.openPopup();
});

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
    if (msg.cmd == 'findBestWindow') {
        let tentativo, wId;
        let queryOpt = {focused: true};
        wId = msg.dp;
        
        chrome.windows.get(wId, tentativo => {
            let rle = chrome.runtime.lastError; 
            if (rle) {
                wId = msg.ow;
                chrome.windows.get(msg.ow, tentativo => {
                    if (tentativo.state == 'minimized') 
                        queryOpt.state = 'normal';
                    chrome.action.setPopup({popup: '../popup.html'}, _ => {
                        chrome.windows.update(wId, queryOpt, _ => {
                            chrome.action.openPopup(_ => {
                                sendResponse({'onse': 'OK'});
                            })
                        })                  
                    })
                })
            } else {
                if (tentativo.state == 'minimized') 
                    queryOpt.state = 'normal';
                chrome.action.setPopup({popup: '../popup.html'}, _ => {
                    chrome.windows.update(wId, queryOpt, _ => {
                        chrome.action.openPopup(_ => {
                            sendResponse({'onse': 'OK'});
                        })
                    })                  
                })                  
            }
        })
    }
    return true
})
/*sw.js - end*/

/*popup.js - begin*/
var sndFloatingWind;
var rv;

function getAllStorage() {
    return new Promise(ok => {
        var proms = [];
        proms.push(chrome.storage.session.get({ 'windVal': 'popup', 'sndFloatingWind': -1 }));
        proms.push(chrome.storage.local.get({'coords': {'x':1, 'y':1}}));
        Promise.all(proms)
            .then(v => {
                ok({...v[0], ...v[1]})
            })  
    })
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async _ => {
    function drawComs() {
        return new Promise(async (ok, ko) => {
            var frag = new DocumentFragment();
            var windVal = rv.windVal;
            
            //Detach Popup
            divEl = document.querySelector('#achPopup');
            divEl.firstElementChild.innerText = (windVal == 'popup' ? 'Det' : 'Att') + 'ach\r\nPopup';
            divEl.setAttribute('status', windVal);
            divEl.addEventListener('click', async function() {
                var precVal = this.getAttribute('status');
                var nextVal = (precVal == 'popup' ? 'window' : 'popup');
                if (nextVal == 'window') {
                    let w = await chrome.windows.getCurrent({populate: true});
                    await chrome.storage.session.set({ 'windVal': nextVal, 'sndDockedPopup': w.id});
                    
                    let itms = await chrome.storage.local.get({'coords': {'x':1, 'y':1}});
                    let coords = itms.coords;
                    
                    let hN = document.querySelector('html');
                    w = await chrome.windows.create({
                        type: 'popup',
                        focused: true,
                        top: coords.y,
                        left: coords.x,
                        height: Math.max(self.outerHeight + 20, hN.scrollHeight + 39),
                        width: Math.max(self.outerWidth, hN.scrollWidth),
                        url: '../popup.html'
                    });

                    sndFloatingWind = w.id;
                    
                    await chrome.storage.session.set({'sndFloatingWind': sndFloatingWind});
                    
                    self.close();
                } else {
                    await chrome.storage.local.set({'coords': {'x': self.screenX, 'y': self.screenY}});
                
                    await chrome.storage.session.set({'windVal': nextVal});
                    
                    let allWinds = await chrome.windows.getAll({'windowTypes': ['normal']});
                    allWinds.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a.id < b.id)
                            return -1
                        else if (a.id > b.id)
                            return 1
                        else return 0
                    });
                    allWinds.sort((a, b) => {
                        if (a.state == 'minimized')
                            return -1;
                        else
                            return 0

                    });
                    
                    let lsw = await chrome.windows.getLastFocused({'windowTypes': ['normal']});
                    if (lsw?.state != 'minimized') {
                        allWinds.splice(allWinds.find(v => {
                            return v.id == lsw.id
                        }), 1);
                        allWinds.unshift(lsw);
                    }

                    let tmp = await chrome.storage.session.get(['sndFloatingWind', 'sndDockedPopup']);

                    let resp = await chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'cmd': 'findBestWindow', 'fw': tmp.sndFloatingWind, 'dp': tmp.sndDockedPopup, 'ow':allWinds[0].id })
                    if (resp.onse == 'OK')
                        self.close();
                    else if (resp.err)
                        alert(risp.err);
                }
            });
            
            ok()
        })
    }
    
    rv = await getAllStorage();
    
    if (rv.windVal == 'popup') {
        if (rv.sndFloatingWind != -1) {
            try {
                let w = await chrome.windows.get(rv.sndFloatingWind);
                if (typeof w !== 'undefined')
                    await chrome.windows.remove(rv.sndFloatingWind);
                await chrome.storage.session.clear('sndFloatingWind')
            } catch(err) {}
        }
    }
    await drawComs()
});

chrome.action.setPopup({popup: ''})
/*popup.js - end*/
```

Comment: Getting errors ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: chrome.action.openPopup is not a function``` and also ```Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'firstElementChild')```.

Comment: does it work for you?

Comment: No. Those errors I mentioned stop it from working.

Comment: My extension is already way ahead with custom stuff so maybe there is some conflict? Can you share yours so I can test it in comparison with mine?

Comment: inside the archive there's also a video: [archive](https://mega.nz/file/hLwRAQxC#T3Mw4ocCAf4owaAVKYtbVYZ2n06dZSORvKi4FgVLJto)

Comment: I tried your extension and although the detach button works, it does not memorize last position and throws a bunch of errors. I used last version of Chrome on last version of macos. Also used last version of Chrome in Windows 10 same problem. But this will be usefull to know how the detach button will work. Memorizing the position would be a nice extra though. Here are the errors from Windows 10: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GTrEF.jpg

Comment: Actually when the extension is detached if I press "attach" it goes back and this will make it memorize the position. Still throwing errors though. After seeing your video again I see that when "attach" is pressed it goes back to Browser in the open state (pretty cool!). With me after pressing "attach" it goes but in the closed state. So maybe this part of the function is the one throwing errors?  I need to understand how this code of yours works and how to apply it to mine. Thank you BTW if this solves my issue I'll accept your answer.

Comment: What is that extension for screen recording btw?

Comment: I don't know what to tell you about this error.
Are you sure they are not old errors? Have you tried cleaning the error console?
Maybe it is only thrown on macOS and\or Safari?
I posted this "trimmed" extension because I had it ready,
but to adapt it to your extension you would have to post your code.
The extension i use for screen recording is [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-recorder/jdopnakmnlnccgpfpmjmdjjohmcdgabp)

Comment: I think it's a bug which has been reported here: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/2602
Maybe you are not using the latest version of Chrome?

Comment: I tried several times on macos and Windows 10 same thing.

Comment: Actually on Windows I'm using 106.0.5249.119 but it's because it's managed by my company.

Comment: I've just tried with Version 110.0.5415.0 (Official Build) canary (64-bit) on Win 10 and it works for me.  
In that report on github I wrote a post but it seems that nobody has read it

Comment: I'll try canary now. But this needs to work for version my company is using. That workaround of yours you wrote on github how does one implement it in this extension you've sent me?

Comment: Yes it works fine on Canary.

Comment: it's not a workaround. I stated only that the method openPopup (still in development) works only with a focused window. So if there is no window focused it need first to put one in focus by hand

  
i.e. **chrome.windows.update(<oneWindowId>, {focused:true}, _ => chrome.action.openPopup())**

Comment: Ok. I think I know how to use your code with my case. Please forgive me if I misunderstood. Actually, I only started coding a couple of months ago so I'm still new to all this. I mean I did some stuff with GAS but that was it.

Comment: No problem. I hope I've helped you in some way. For macOS - Safari I can't do tests because I only use pc window both at home and at work.

Comment: Np. I'll let you know if your answer worked later on. Thanks :)

Comment: Ok, it works with my use case after some changes. Now have to wait for my company to update to Canary X'D. Thanks again mate! Answered accepted!